# Error occured while adding data to remote MySql server

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, file-upload, .net-core

I am trying to upload new post in remote SQl server, everything works fine but when i choose photo in upload it say "error occured while processing your request", this works great on localhost server but not in remote server

public async Task NewPost([Bind("Id,Title,PhotoUrl,Category,Description,")]Post post)
        {

```
        var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
        foreach (var Image in files)
        {
            if (Image != null && Image.Length > 0)
            {

                var file = Image;
                var uploads = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot/postimages");

                if (file.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse
                        (file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

                    System.Console.WriteLine(fileName);
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                        post.PhotoUrl = file.FileName;
                    }


                }
            }
        }
            post.Author = _user.GetUserName(HttpContext.User);
        _context.Posts.Add(post);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }
```

it works perfectly on local server,

Comment: if this is a 500 error you may have to check the error logs. where have you hosted it? If you host it in azure web app you can check the logs. if you used linux you could use journal.

Comment: i have hosted it in smarterasp.net

Comment: the problem is only with photo upload.. when i add post without photo it works..

Comment: https://www.smarterasp.net/support/kb/a1883/asp_net-core-module-configuration-examples.aspx
you can check this to setup logging. checking the logs will show you the real error when you get bad request

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be a storage permissions issue. It works fine in localhost and shows errors only in the server. Moreover, in your comments, you mentioned this is in a shared hosting solution. In shared hosting for windows, you will have to specifically give permissions for your IIS user for a specific folder. This can be done in your hosting provider's website (you may have a console such as parallels).

Comment: the problem is only with upload in site.. i can upload from filezilla but not from my site

Comment: yes uploading from filezilla means your ftp user has access to your folder. the website connects to the folder via a different user. you will need to give that user write permissions to that specific folder

Comment: how do i give write permission.?

Comment: login into your hosting website and look for a folders option. I generally find the permissions option there. if you can't find this option. ask the hosting's support on how to add write permissions on a folder for websites